# Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'A' in trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-error-1442

I have the following problem with mysql:
I have the table A with a trigger that update a columns of table B when something in A change. This trigger works.

I need te possibility to update a column of A when something in B change, but the second trigger generate the error.
I know is recursive, but how can I do it?

exp.

```
    trigger A:
delimiter $$

CREATE TRIGGER TAU_A
AFTER UPDATE ON table_A FOR EACH ROW
       begin
      IF OLD.to_read <> NEW.to_read THEN
            update table_B
            set is_read=if(new.to_read=1,0,1)
            where id=new.id;
      END IF;
       
END$$

trigger B:
delimiter $$

CREATE TRIGGER TAU_B
AFTER UPDATE ON table_b FOR EACH ROW
       begin
      IF OLD.is_read <> NEW.is_readTHEN
            update table_a
            set to_read=if(new.is_read=1,0,1)
            where id=new.id;
      END IF;
       
END$$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use user-defined variable, check for chaining update.

### DEMO

`@check_for_cycle` user-defined variable is used for to prevent a cycle. The variable name must be unique over a system (i.e. it must be used in this triggers pack only) and provide interference absence (including another applications which may modify these tables data).

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (id INT PRIMARY KEY, val INT);
CREATE TABLE t2 (id INT PRIMARY KEY, val INT);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1,1), (2,2);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (1,1), (3,3);
SELECT * FROM t1;
SELECT * FROM t2;
```

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_au_t1
AFTER UPDATE ON t1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF @check_for_cycle IS NULL THEN
        SET @check_for_cycle := 1;
        UPDATE t2 SET val = NEW.val + 10 WHERE id = NEW.id;
        SET @check_for_cycle := NULL;
    END IF;
END
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_au_t2
AFTER UPDATE ON t2
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF @check_for_cycle IS NULL THEN
        SET @check_for_cycle := 1;
        UPDATE t1 SET val = NEW.val + 100 WHERE id = NEW.id;
        SET @check_for_cycle := NULL;
    END IF;
END
```

```
UPDATE t1 SET val = val + 1;
SELECT * FROM t1;
SELECT * FROM t2;
```

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 3 | 3 |

```
UPDATE t2 SET val = val + 2;
SELECT * FROM t1;
SELECT * FROM t2;
```

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 114 |
| 2 | 3 |

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 14 |
| 3 | 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5FGH4O99)

---

You must check that no error occures in a trigger, and clear the variable in the error handler. Otherwise, when INSERT fails then the trigger breaks and the whole process rollbacks, but the variable value will stay non-cleared (variable assignment is not rollbacked) which will lock trigger action for further updates.